# Phonegap/Cordova 2.0 - Not populating within app

Tags: ios, cordova

I have created one project successfully with Cordova2.0 on iOS.  That was the first project that I created in cordova2.0 and everything went well.

The issue comes when I attempted to create another new project with cordova2.0 in IOS and the project is nearly fully created except that the cordovaLib.xcodeporj package is empty and the app will not even run its initial build.

Has anyone else had this issue? If so, what was your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have the first project open. You cannot have the cordova sub-project open in two projects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the bin directory to your home and ran the command from there? This issue happened to me when I ran with bin directory from the mounted installer.